# Shorter functional expressions in Python: a shortcut for lambda

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I know this may sound a silly question, but coming from Scala, I really appreciate the short notation used with functional expressions involving the placeholder `_`.

For example in Scala, to do a mapping

```
val x = Seq(1,2,3)
val y = x.map(_+1)
```

The equivalent in Python requires the usage of `lambda` which makes the expression much longer:

```
x = list(1,2,3)
y = list(map(lambda v: v+1, x))
```

Is it programmed in Python to somewhat introduce the placeholder symbol `_` in future versions for notational brevity, when clear from the context?

Comment: No, but generally you should avoid lambda anyway. Most use cases would be better served with some comprehension construct rather than an anonymous function and `map`/`filter`

Comment: Many of the circumstances in which comprehensions are better in python are *because* lambdas are so verbose.